# I have a lack of performance in a multitask C program running on a micro-controller. How can I find its source?

Tags: c, performance, debugging, microcontroller, multitasking

I am working on a C-program that runs on a 32bit microcontroller. This program has been written 10 years ago by functional specialists for another architecture and I do not know well how it should behave (its made to manage a chiller and I have very few notions of thermodynamics and there is nearly no documentation about how the code is structured). My work was to migrate it on the new architecture and I am almost done. Actually, I am beginning to validate my development. And now, I am worried because, if the core function of the program seems to work more or less, it seems very slow to me and it also generated many HMI errors (which I know is probably due to the lack of performance).

Knowing that I migrated my code quite blindly and do not master its internal logics, I wondered how I can confirm my belief and improve the performances.

About its structure, it is a multitask program - something like 30 tasks are potentially running, the majority are scheduled periodically, some are scheduled only when conditions are met and some are meant to be stopped after a few runs.
It includes also reading and writing in a flash drive that is known to be very small - maybe too small to meet the program's requirements, and network communications (which seems to be quite OK to me).

Do you have strategies in mind that would help me find my issue? Ideas of how I could investigate in such a mess?

I know its is a broad question, and I am not sure it meets Stack Overflow requirements. If it does not, I will gladly accept any explanation of what I did wrong and how I can write a better question.

Regards.

Comment: Sounds like a real mess - it also sounds like the company you work at doesn't have any kind of formal processes for software development, testing, quality control, etc ? Are there no requirements/design documents, test plans, etc ? What does your manager think about all this ?

Comment: How could your program be slower than it was on the old MCU? That doesn't make any sense and suggests a poor choice of MCU and/or clock. Out of curiousity, which was the old MCU and which one did you port to?

Comment: @Paul R: nice guess. There is very few development process. Computing is not their core work and they basically do not care about it. The IT team manager disagrees with this philosophy but its management does not want to spend money on "non-productive matters" even if they got warned many times that it will cost them more in the end. The only documentation they agrees with is functional one - the one that will explain how the software should interact with the chillers' components. For the purely technical information... Well, there is people's memory...

Comment: @Lundin: Wrong choice of MCU, in fact. They used a customed 16-bits microcontroller with 1GB flash memory. Now, they use a 32-bits SAIA Burgess MCU, with a 8MB flash memory. The memory is just not enough for the program's data so a routine provided by SAIA compresses frequently the files. The program being quite slow - or the tasks badly scheduled - it seems to me that there is some kind of collision between the SAIA's compressing task and the programs' tasks.

Comment: Commiserations - sounds like an unpleasant work culture in which to be a software engineer - if you can't get them to wake up to the long-term consequences of slapdash software development then it might be a good idea to start looking for another job...